# Why isn't this Child Computed Observable updated when it's observed array gets pushed to?

Tags: knockout.js, computed-observable

I have a simple example to illistrate this. Take a which simply holds an array of items.  Each row has a observable property, a date in this case. The ui is bound to a set of sorted items, which is just an computed observable. This computed observable in turn is watching a computed observable which will filter out rows.

Why does this not cascade as desired?

```
//simple table model
var TableModel = function(){
var self = this;
self.items = ko.observableArray([
new TableRowModel(5),
new TableRowModel(2),
new TableRowModel(9),
new TableRowModel(7)
]);
 self.filtered = ko.computed(function(){
return [self.items()[0], self.items()[1], self.items()[2]];
 });
 self.sortedItems = ko.computed(function(){
return _.sortBy(self.filtered(), function(item){
    return item.value();
});
});
};

var TableRowModel = function(value){
  var self = this;

self.value = ko.observable(new Date(2013, value, 1));
};

var model = new TableModel();
ko.applyBindings(model);

model.items.push(new TableRowModel(1));
```

Comment: Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/tyzy5/19/
Where's my February entry? It should be first on this list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is working fine in your code. "February" is not there because it is filtered out.

The `push()` method **inserts the new item at the last position.** But in your `self.filtered` you only displays the items which are the position 0, 1, 2. But when you call `push` in your code the new item will be insterted at position 4 so it won't be displayed.

If you want "February" to be displayed you can use `unshift`:

> myObservableArray.unshift('Some new value') inserts a new item at the beginning of the array

So in your code:

```
model.items.unshift(new TableRowModel(1));
```

Here is an updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/hnkqP/).

Comment: Nemesv, I'll give you the answer, as your very correct as it's written.

Comment: I tried to re-create the problem using my actual source, sans the server-interacting logic, but couldn't reproduce the problem. If you are familiar with ASP.NET MVC, would you be willing to look at my original source?

I feel I've not helped the community out with this question at this point, as I've basically posted a trivial issue, and can't seem to duplicate/demonstrate the one I'm having in dev.

Comment: Nevermind! I have discovered my problem. observableArray's do not listen to child objects's updated values (by default), only that a new object had been removed/added to the array.

Comment: @OliverKane yes you are right: `An observableArray tracks which objects are in the array, not the state of those objects` as stated in the [documentation.](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)